# Angular-jsdoc - how to document complex method

Tags: angularjs, jsdoc

I started to use angular-jsdoc for document my AngularJS code.
I have a service with some methods.

Some of the methods, return an object with another methods:
Here is an example of my service (with simple method and complex method)

```
angular.module('map').service('pointUtils', function ($http) {
    var self = this;

    // simple function
    self.removeAllPoints = function () {
        // remove all points
    };

    // complex function
    self.createPoint = function (params) {
        var pointData = {
            isVisible :params.isVisible || true,
            color : params.color || 'blue'
        };

        var pointObj = {};

        pointObj.setColor = function (color) {
            pointData.color = color;
        };
        pointObj.getColor = function () {
            return pointData.color;
        };
        pointObj.setVisible = function (visible) {
            pointData.isVisible = visible;
        };

        return pointObj
    };
});
```

what is the way to document this complex method?

thanks,
kfir